# Problems with JList

Tags: java, jlist

Our teacher doesn't want us doing anything inside of the GUI class so all of our adding and removing of elements has to be outside in its own class. I've read about vectors and the adding and removing of elements in JList but like i stated we are not allowed to do it that way. My question is how i would go about clearing my list or refreshing it when I need to populate it with a new one or update the original. What my problem is the list duplicates itself every time I click the open button, When what I need it to do is refresh every time it is clicked.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.io.*;

/* Simple example of using the contents of a file to populate a JList
 * 
 * @author Jill Courte
 */

public class JListFromFile extends JFrame {

  private TextField wordA;
  private TextField wordB;
  private JButton openButton;
  private JButton newButton;
  private JButton addButton;
  private JButton deleteButton;
  private JButton saveButton;
  private TextField output;
  private JList listFromFile;
  private JPanel listPanel;
  private JPanel textPanel;
  private JPanel inputPanel;
  private JPanel buttonsPanel;
  private DataSource2 dataSource;
  private WordPair wordPair;
  public JListFromFile ()
  {
    // create the object to provide the data
    dataSource = new DataSource2();
    wordPair = new WordPair();
    // use a border layout for the main window
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(20, 20));

    buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    openButton = new JButton("Open");
    newButton = new JButton("New");
    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
    saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    addButton.setEnabled( false ); 
    deleteButton.setEnabled( false );
    saveButton.setEnabled( false );
    buttonsPanel.add(openButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(newButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(addButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(deleteButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(saveButton);

    //add the button listeners
    openButton.addActionListener(new OpenButtonListener());
    addButton.addActionListener(new AddButtonListener());

    add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // create the panel to hold the list
    listPanel = new JPanel();

    // create your JList
    listFromFile = new JList();
    listFromFile.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    listFromFile.setSelectedIndex(0);

    //add the list selection listener
   listFromFile.addListSelectionListener(new WordSelection());

    //add the translation text box 
    textPanel = new JPanel();
    output = new TextField();
    output.setEditable(false);
    output.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
    textPanel.add(output);

    // add scroll bars to list 
    JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(listFromFile);
    listScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 200));

    //add user input textfield 
    wordA = new TextField ("Word to Add");
    wordB = new TextField ("Translated word");
    wordA.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
    wordB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
    wordA.setEnabled(false);
    wordB.setEnabled(false);

    //create panel to hold input textfield
    inputPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel.add(wordA);
    inputPanel.add(wordB);

    //add the list (via the scroll pane) to the panel
    listPanel.add(listScrollPane);

    //add the panels to the frame
    add(listPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
  }


  private File findFile ()
  { 
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

    // Start in current directory
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
    int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);      

    if (status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No File Selected");
      throw new NoFileChoosenException();
    }
    else
    {    
      File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

      System.out.println(file.getName());      
      System.out.println(file.getPath());


      return file;
    }
  }


  private class OpenButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {

      File file = null;

      try
      {
        file = findFile();

        //tell the data source what file to use
        dataSource.readDataFromFile(file);

        //JList needs an array of strings, retrieve it from the data source
        String [] data = dataSource.getData();

        data = dataSource.insertion(data);
        data = wordPair.remove(data);
        listFromFile.setListData(data);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      { 
      }
      addButton.setEnabled(true); 
      deleteButton.setEnabled(true);
      saveButton.setEnabled(true);
      wordA.setEnabled(false);
      wordB.setEnabled(false);
    }
  }

  private class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
      wordA.setEnabled(true);
      wordB.setEnabled(true);

    }
  }

  private class WordSelection implements ListSelectionListener
     {
      public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent event)
      {
          int index = listFromFile.getSelectedIndex();
          if (index >= 0)
          {
           String s = wordPair.getWord(2, index);
           output.setText(s);
          }
      }
     }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JListFromFile jListFromFile = new JListFromFile();
    jListFromFile.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds very vague to me what you are allowed to and not allowed to do. Consider asking your teacher for clarifications about this.

Comment: You are using `setListData`, which creates a new `ListModel` each time it is called, therefore, the problem is not with the `JList` or the way you are using it, but (most likely) with `DataSource2`...

Comment: Usually you will call repaint() method of your visual components after the content is changed. But may be I misunderstood what you need

Comment: @GermannArlington: this is not true at all when the change involves replacing a list model or adding data to a new list model. The model should call a fireXXX method internally when changes occur, notifying listeners from the GUI of the change, and so the component updates automatically. Same thing occurs when you call `setText(...)` on a JLabel or JTextComponent. Notice that you never need to call repaint for them either.

Comment: @hovercraft-full-of-eels, So should i be calling a "clear" method outside of the GUI to get the results I want. I think your understanding what i'm asking for....As were not supposed to be refreshing the jList inside of the GUI class.

Comment: user2763148: my reply was for @GermannArlington. Check MadProgrammer's suggestion above for more about your problem.